# Android Studio cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add OSMDroidBonusPack library to my project, so I made a `libs` folder and dragged&dropped the jar file into it. When I right click on the jar file and choose `Add As Library` Android Studio says :

**Android Studio cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain.**
**Choose the appropriate categories from the list.**
**- classes**
**- external annotations**
**- jar directory**
**- JavaDocs**
**- source archive directory**
**- sources**

What does this mean ?

Comment: Where did you create the **libs** folder? When Android Studio creates projects via the New Project Wizard, it puts a **libs** directory in each module that you can drop **.jar** files into, and you shouldn't need to do anything (i.e. you don't need to modify the build scripts) for it to pick those up; it's automatic. Well, it's automatic after you click the **Sync with Gradle Files** button in the toolbar.

Comment: When in `Project` structure view, I have 2 root directories : My project's folder and `External Libraries`. My Project's folder contains : a folder with my application's name, a `library` folder and others. I made the `libs` folder inside the folder with my application's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar file I used was corrupted, I thinks that's why Android Studio couldn't read it. I used an older version and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The reason for this is that the jar package is empty.

[image]

You need the right jar package.